# JavaScript - How do I assign data read from Ionic storage in a promise to a variable

Tags: ionic3, local-storage, storage

I have been trying to save then retrieve a simple key/data pair using the Ionic storage component rather than use the basic browser local storage.

All of the examples I can find online use the info directly from the Ionic documentation, as below

> storage.set('name', 'Max');
>
> storage.get('name').then((val) => {console.log('Your name is', **val**);});

The storage.get works fine when doing a simple console.log, but fails when I try to assign **val** directly to a variable, it always returns undefined.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

is it possible that the promise has not resolved at the point when you are assigning the variable? You can try this...

```js
  mydata: any;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.storage.set('name', 'Max');

    this.storage.get('name').then((val) => {
        // this is a good time to assign the variable.
        this.mydata = val;
        console.log(this.mydata);
    });

  }
```